# Get PHP ssl session id

Tags: php, session, ssl

I want to get the ssl session id so I know that it is the same user. When I try `$_SERVER['ssl_session_id']` it returns nothing and doing `print_r($_SERVER)` `$_SERVER['ssl_session_id']` doesn't show up.

The reason I need to have the ssl session id is I'm creating a login system and would like to make sure the session can't be used through a fixation attack. I am going to add it to the auth session cookie and then can check it later.

EDIT:
From the answers and comments I have gotten:
It changes every request and isn't something that is stored in a $_SERVER or $_SESSION super global array; therefore is useless for using on the web and shouldn't be used.

Comment: SSL_SESSION_ID it is not always set by SSL / by the SSL implementation of your webserver. (apache?) [read on here](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&tmp_geoLoc=true&docname=c02670261). Would you mind to explain in an edit why you want to use this variable? Whats the purpose?

Comment: Do you by chance have a confusion between SSL and PHP sessions are are just looking for [`session_id()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.session-id.php)? Using SSL_SESSION_ID to check if its the same user seems wrong to me.

Comment: It is indeed wrong. The same user may have several SSL session IDs over a very short space of time, changing as often as either end decides to expire them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have learned from comments and research is that you can't get the ssl_session_id through PHP and even if you could it changes therefore isn't useful. Thank you to the people who answered and commented.

Answer (score 0):

Did you do

```
session_start();
```

before trying to access the session? If yes, then your sessions are broken somehow (cookie not set correct, so a new session is started continually), or you didn't save that value into the session to begin with.

$_SERVER has nothing to do with the session. it's a superglobal that contains information about the server and PHP's configuration. $_SERVER is its own dedicated superglobal, and is purely for server data.

Comment: Isn't the ssl session id a non-changeable value? Could you please give me a code example - I just tried print_r($_SESSION) and it showed only what I had set

Comment: You meant "and is purely for server data." instead of "and is purely for session data." i guess.

Comment: You said that I have to set it in the session to begin with. How do I get it to begin with? It is set by SSL isn't it?

Comment: I read on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation#Solution:_Utilize_SSL_.2F_TLS_Session_identifier) that SSL/TLS sets a session identifier and that use of it is very secure

Comment: ssl session ids are pointless in a web context, since an ssl connection is setup/torn down for every request. PHP will not record any such ID in $_SESSION or $_SERVER because it's useless temporary information which cannot be applied from one request to another.

Comment: The SSL Session ID is completely unrelated to the PHP Session ID created by `session_start()`.